# associative array -plsql

Tags: sql, plsql, associative-array

I am having problem with associative array in PLSQL. When I run a cursor and try to insert every single row from a cursor into a variable(which is declared as cursor%rowtype; ech row in a cursor contains first name and last name), and then display the output, it works. When I try to do the same thing but instead of variable I use associative array, it does not work.

So this works

```
declare
   cursor cur is select last_name, first_name from employees;
   v_table_emp cur%rowtype;
   begin
   for item in cur
   loop
   v_table_emp:=item;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_table_emp.last_name );
   end loop;
   end;
```

And this does not

```
declare
   cursor cur is select last_name, first_name from employees;
   v_table_emp cur%rowtype;
   type table_emp is table of v_table_emp;
   c_table_emp table_emp;
   begin
   for item in cur
   loop
   v_table_emp:=item;
   c_table_emp:=v_table_emp;
   dbms_output.put_line(c_table_emp.last_name );
   end loop;
   end;
```

So if you can help me I would appreciate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to use is not an associative array, and you have some issues;
assuming that you want to define a cursor, fetch it into a variable and then scan the result, this is a working example:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cur
    IS
        SELECT last_name, first_name FROM employees;

    TYPE tTableEmp IS TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE;
    vTableEmp tTableEmp;
BEGIN
    open cur;
    fetch cur bulk collect into vTableEMp;
    close cur;
    
    if vTableEmp.count != 0 then
        for i in 1 .. vTableEMp.count loop
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (vTableEMp(i).last_name);
        end loop;
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Empty');
    end if;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.

Comment: You don't need to check the collection count for non-zero if you loop over it in this way: looping from 1 to zero will perform no iterations.